# Testing mvvm models with moq - constructor takes dependencyContainer as parameter

Tags: c#, moq, mugenmvvmtoolkit

I'm trying to test my mvvm models which are developed with autofac and MugenMvvmToolkit. I followed the following tutorial (https://mugenmvvmtoolkit.readme.io/docs/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-viewmodels) but when I create my setup method i get the following error:

```
Message: 
    System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterSource(Autofac.ContainerBuilder, Autofac.Core.IRegistrationSource)'.
  Stack Trace: 
    AutofacContainer.ctor(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
    AutofacContainer.ctor()
    UnitTest1.ctor() line 20
```

I have no clue why this is my code so far (one remark I use xunit instead of Nunit):

```
using System;
using Moq;
using MugenMvvmToolkit;
using MugenMvvmToolkit.Infrastructure;
using MugenMvvmToolkit.Interfaces;
using MugenMvvmToolkit.Interfaces.Presenters;
using MugenMvvmToolkit.Models;
using Xunit;

namespace Mobile.Pull.Agro.Tests
{
    public class UnitTest1 : UnitTestBase
    {
        public UnitTest1()
        {
            _viewModelPresenterMock = new Mock<IViewModelPresenter>();
            _serializer = new Serializer(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
            var container = new AutofacContainer();
            container.BindToConstant(_viewModelPresenterMock.Object);
            Initialize(container, new DefaultUnitTestModule());
            ApplicationSettings.CommandExecutionMode = CommandExecutionMode.None;
        }

        private Mock<IViewModelPresenter> _viewModelPresenterMock;
        private ISerializer _serializer;

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
           Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided the exception that you're getting, which makes it difficult to help.

Comment: I updated the complete question :-)

Comment: Please check that you're using the same Autofac version in all projects this error looks like you have 2 different version of Autofac and it leads to conflict